# What design pattern to use in this situation?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have 40 suppliers that need to make an ftp connection, do something there and close the connection. So, all of those 40 suppliers have their own class and they all have the connection and disconnection of the ftp server, but they all have different processing methods.

So basically I have 40 classes with this method:

```
ftp.Connect();
//do something - this is different for all the classes
ftp.Close();
```

So the do something part is different for all, it does different things, it uses different variables, etc.

What I thought I would do is: create a new class that would be instantiated in all the 40 suppliers. This class will have one method that look something like this:

```
public void Connect(FTPCredentials credentials, Process process)
{
    var ftp = new FtpConnection(credentials.Host, credentials.Username, credentials.Password);
    ftp.Open();
    ftp.Login();

    process(ftp);

    ftp.Close();
}

public delegate void Process(FtpConnection ftp/*, string name*/);
```

The problem I have here is that all the methods in all 40 suppliers have different input parameters so what would the input parameters of Process be? Also, I think I don't gain much because I still have the FtpConnection ftp parameter here which means that I will have to add the dll that has the class FtpConnection in every project that will use the Connect method.

For example, the process method in the suppliers would look like this:

```
process(string fileName) //and it would download fileName
process(string folderName) //create folder if it doesnt exist
```

Is there a design pattern I can use here that would be cleaner and would make things easier?

Comment: You could simply override the `Process` method (parameter as a `List`) or may I missing something?

Comment: Connect/close can be in fact constructor/dispose (an ability to replace that with [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement), see `IDisposable`. As for different methods you can use generics to supply parameters as settings class, e.g. `using (var connection = new FTPConnection<SettingsForFolder>(...) { ... }`, the instance of settings can be even set as constructor parameter and then accessed without need to supply it for every `Process()` call.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that such an object is used only shortly and for a single specific purpose. So I would accept specific parameters to be stored in a specific derived class. Similar to mybirthname's solution, I'd start with an abstract class, but define it differently:

```
public abstract class BaseSupplier
{
    protected BaseSupplier(FtpCredentials credentials)
    {
        _Credentials = credentials;
    }
    private FtpCredentials _Credentials;

    public void Run()
    {
        Connect();
        Process();
        Disconnect();
    }

    private void Connect() {/* your connection and login code */}
    private void Disconnect() {/* your disconnect code */}
    protected abstract void Process(); // to be filled in the derived class
}

public class ConcreteSupplier
{
    public ConcreteSupplier(FtpCredentials credentials, SomeType parameter) : base(credentials)
    { /* store extra parameters */ }

    override Process() {/*your concrete processing code */ }
}
```

If I remember correctly, That's called the Strategy Pattern.

Edit:
juunas is right, it's the Template Method pattern. In Gamma et al., Template Method is described directly after Strategy in the chapter on Behavioral Patterns.

Comment: *Template method* pattern

Answer (score 0):

Create abstract class

```
    public abstract class BaseSupplier
    {

        public void Connect(FTPCredentials credentials, Process process, SupplierSettingClass settings)
        {
             var ftp = new FtpConnection(credentials.Host, credentials.Username, credentials.Password);
             ftp.Open();
             ftp.Login();

             DoSomething(settings);

             ftp.Close();
        }

        public virtual void DoSomething(SupplierSettingClass settings)
        {
             //define base case;
        }
    }
```

You need to create SupplierSettingClass in which you will implement every input parameter for DoSomething method as property (folderName, fieldName and so on)

```
    public class SupplierSettingClass
    {
        public string FolderName {get; set;}

        //and so on;
    }
```

In the end in the SupplierA

```
    public class SupplierA:BaseSupplier
    {
         public override void DoSomething(SupplierSettingClass settings)
         {
              //Do specific stuff for your class.
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some clever inheritance to contain pretty much all of the required behaviour in one base `abstract` class, like this:

```
public interface IProcessor
{
    void Process(Credentials credentials);
}

public class Credentials
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SupplierBase : IProcessor, IDisposable
{
    protected FtpConnection _Connection;

    private void Connect(Credentials credentials)
    {
        //Create the ftp connection
        _Connection = new FtpConnection(credentials.Host, credentials.Username, credentials.Password);
        _Connection.Open();
        _Connection.Login();
    }

    private void Disconnect()
    {
        //Close and dispose the ftp connection
        _Connection.Close();
        _Connection.Dispose();
        _Connection = null;
    }

    public void Process(Credentials credentials)
    {
        Connect(credentials);
        Execute();
        Disconnect();
    }

    protected abstract void Execute();

    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_Connection != null)
            {
                _Connection.Dispose();
                _Connection = null;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public void MySupplier : SupplierBase
{
    //You can add unique supplier properties here.
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute()
    {
        //Implementation here
        Console.WriteLine(SomeProperty);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how you would call it:

```
Credentials creds = new Credentials()
{
    Host = "127.0.0.1",
    Username = "test",
    Password = "test"
};

MySupplier sup1 = new MySupplier();
sup1.SomeProperty = "Hello";
sup1.Process(creds);
```

OR

```
using (MySupplier sup1 = new MySupplier())
{
    sup1.SomeProperty = "Hello";
    sup1.Process(creds);
}
```